# Read a serverside file using HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm new in HTML5 programming. I'm porting my mobile games to HTML5. I have lots of text files which are located on server's folders, so I'd like to read a file from known url and I don't know how to do it. I found a tutorial but there are the file reads from the local folder: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Would you mind provide me an example how to read a serverside file from known url in the simplest way?

Thanks and peace to all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have look to : [Jquery Ajax Calling functions](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/07/jquery-ajax-calling-functions.html)

make use of jquery make your task easy

```
jQuery.get('http://localhost/foo.txt', function(data) {
    var myvar = data;
});
```

Comment: Also worth noting that you don't need html5 to do this - reading clientside files requires html5 apis, but this works back to IE6.

Comment: Exactly. His question incorrectly asked about html5, but the correct answer has nothing to do with html5. I wanted to clarify to Yakov that this isn't a new thing, and doesn't have anything to do with html5.

Answer (score 1):

And if you are not using jQuery you can take a look at this [Ajax example](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php).